# All data points doesn't show up in stacked bar chart

Tags: javascript, c3.js

Hi All I am feeding following data to c3 stacked bar chart.

```
["x","Mar 2017","Apr 2017","May 2017","Jun 2017","Jul 2017","Aug 2017","Sep 2017","Oct 2017","Nov 2017","Dec 2017","Jan 2018","Feb 2018"],
["product0","4","-4","12","-20","44","-84","172","-340","684","-1364","2732","-5460"],
["product1","10","15","20","25","30","40","40","70","50","160","65","475"],
["product2","6","10","14","18","22","26","30","34","38","42","46","50"]
```

As you can see numbers range from -5460  to 2732.
With above data I am not getting all the data points in the tooltip for columns which has smaller numbers. For example first column contain values 4,10,6 for product0, product1 and product2 respectively. When I hover on the chart for first column in tooltip only 10 and 6 comes up but not 4.

My tooltip setting is like below

```
 tooltip: {             
            grouped: false,
            format: d3.format('.2f')
        },
```

If set grouped: true  then everything works fine. But I don't want grouping as it doesn't look good if there are lots of data. Is there any settings I need to enable to fix this?  Here is the fiddle for you to try out http://jsfiddle.net/z7muypnh/2/

Answer (score 1):

the data is too small to see.you want to draw bar in range (-5500,3000) into  a bar chart which height default is 400px.if you want to see the small data you can change the axis y height or group data in tooltip.I choose the last one.see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z7muypnh/5/).

```
 tooltip: {             
    grouped: true,
    format: d3.format('.2f')
 }
```

if you wan't to set the tooltip grouped,you can only set axis y height below,see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z7muypnh/6/):

```
 size:{
    height:(3000- -5000)
 }
```

Comment: Your solution did work but height of the bar does not look  presentable